# What do you call your US States table?

Tags: sql, database, states

Silly question for the masses: Assume you have a table that handles the state of your object as it passes through your workflow.

Now assume you have a standard United States State table...

What do you call your US State table, without being redundant?

Additional Constraint - You can't pluralize your tables.

Some thoughts:

```
UnitedState
StateOfUnion
UnionizedState
AmericanState
```

Curious to see what other people come up with...

Comment: Will the table always be limited to US states? I tend to default to StatesAndProvinces (or StateOrProvince in the singular case) to cover my bases.

Comment: Pretty sure we arn't going to be adding any more states in the foreseeable future, so why is a DB table necessary? Unless West Virginia finally decides to change it's name to something else so that it can stop copying it's eastern brother.

Comment: States only. No Provinces (though it was discussed). And we need States for relational purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

USAState

Or if you want to include the country in each record call it GeographicState

Comment: If you want to make it *really* multi-purpose, use something other than "state" - not every country is divided into states - most have provinces, some have other entities....

Answer (score 7):

`CountryDivision` would be pretty global

```
CountryDivisionId
CountryId
Name ("Texas", "Ontario", ...)
```

and a `Country` table

```
CountryId
CountryDivisionAlias ("State", "Province", ...)
Name ("United States of America", "Canada", ..)
```

Comment: Not bad... though slightly - pardon the pun - divisive.

Comment: I leaves open the possibility of countries not having divisions of itself. It could even be further extended with a `CountryDivisionDivision` or some such nonsense for United States State Counties or perhaps using a single table like `EarthEntity` with a nullable `ParentEarthEntityId`, hah!

Answer (score 2):

StateProvince that stores states & provinces in multiple countries

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to change the geographic states table.  Why not name the Workflow States table WorkflowState, WorkflowObjectState, ObjectState, etc.

Also, I tend to put geographic states into in memory collections instead of the database.

Comment: Because "State" becomes too ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

What about AddressState?  Keeps it a little more globalised...

Comment: Hardly any other country in the world is divided into "states" - so this is really not all that "globalized".....

Comment: Germany, Australia, India, Mexico, Malaysia, and Brazil, just to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

`Provinces`-  This addresses both states and provinces as in some countries.

Answer (score 0):

I've traditionally used `USStates` for this, short for "United State's States", the full version's a bit less intuitive than the short...but the short's what you're looking at all the time.

Some other examples:

- `AUStates` - Australia
- `MXStates` - Mexico
- `INStates` - India

Just using the country prefix works, *if* you're storing a different set of data for each country, if you're not doing that, there's no need for multiple tables in the first place.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that, because then it technically reads "United States States"

Comment: @AlishahNovin - They *are* the "United State's States", e.g. States belonging to the United States, possessive :)

Comment: United States' States, to be technical.

Answer (score 0):

i call one STATUS
and the other STATE

Comment: Status was actually veto'd :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used Regions but we were tracking more than just the names of states. We wanted the ability to breakdown or buildup other areas by geoloc such as cities, neighborhoods, businesses, etc

Answer (score 0):

How about `USGeoState`?

Answer (score 0):

How about State_Squared ? 
:^)